# Insert images in multiple pages in pdf

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

Is it is possible to change the following code in order to create the images in the beginning and use their references in the pages in which I want to insert the specific image?

```
using (Stream inputPdfStream  = new FileStream("sample.pdf", FileMode.Open, 
                                               FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream("result.pdf", FileMode.Create, 
                                               FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    var reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);
    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = null;

    int c = reader.NumberOfPages;
    string fnmae = "";
    iTextSharp.text.Image image = null;

    for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
    {
        fnmae = (i % 2==0) ? "1.jpg" : "6.jpg";
        image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(fnmae);
        pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
        image.ScaleToFit(100, 100);
        image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
        pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
    }

    stamper.Close();
}
```

Comment: are u using `iTextSharp.dll`?

Comment: yes i am using iTextSharp.dll